# Variance of product of variables

Tags: variance

I have a question on behalf of a friend.

Given the following values:

```
p=0.193
n=4778
beta=1.94E-01
SE(beta)= 2.72E-02
```

And this fact:

```
var(p) = p*(1-p)/n
```

What is the overall variance of this?

```
var( 2 * p * (1-p) * beta**2 )
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is p a number? Why does the variance of p depend on p?

Comment: you have to explain your variables

Comment: @dimpol p is a probability (of genetic association between a genotype and a phenotype). beta is an effect size. Both are calculated with the software GEMMA.

Comment: If $p$ is "calculated," that like is an *estimate* based on data.  Therefore it sounds like $p$ also is a random variable.  That further suggests that maybe $p$ and $\beta$ are simultaneous outputs of some statistical estimating procedure, which means they could be correlated.  All this information is of critical importance for understanding and answering your question.  Please edit it to provide further details and context.

Answer (score 1):

These transformations might help you assuming I understood your question correctly.

$$\begin{equation}
{\rm Var}(X + Y) = {\rm Var}(X) + {\rm Var}(Y) + 2 {\rm Cov}(X,Y)\\
\end{equation}$$

$$\begin{equation}
{\rm Var}(aX + b) = a^2 {\rm Var}(X)
\end{equation}$$

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent then.

$$\begin{equation}
{\rm Var}(X + Y) = {\rm Var}(X) + {\rm Var}(Y)\\
\end{equation}$$

This would be my stab at it.

$${\rm Var}( 2 p  (1-p)  \beta^2 ) = (2\beta^2)^2({\rm Var}(p) + {\rm Var}(p^2) + 2{\rm Cov}(p,p^2))$$

which leads you a new question of what is the ${\rm Var}(p^2)$ and ${\rm Cov}(p,p^2)$

If you know the distribution of p you should be able to get a moment generating function which can help find all the above. Would need the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, and 4th moments. Hopefully they exist!

Then you could use the following:

$Var(X^2) = E(X^4) - (E(X^2))^2$

$Cov(X,X^2) = E(X^3) - [E(X)E(X^2)]$